# Binding a text file to a local port to read from it

Tags: python, file, sockets, pyspark

I am looking for a way to bind a text file to a port on my machine in Python, the same way as what the flowing Linux command do

```
cat myfile.txt | pv -l -L 2000 -q | nc -lk 9999
```

I want this on Windows, so I cannot use the above command directly as it is. I want to do this because then I have another Python code (using pyspark) which reads data from this port as a stream.

```
data = StreamingContext(sc, 1).socketTextStream("localhost", 9999)
```

Answer (score 1):

https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html is probably the relevant docs.

I don't know anything about pyspark, but my guess something along these lines:

```
import socket
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind(('', 9999))
s.listen(1)
con, adr = s.accept()
with open('myfile.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        con.sendall(line)
con.close()
```

should work.  It's sending line by line, which may work for your usecase (I note it's a textfile).

If you'd like a bit of stats being printed while you're going:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import sys
import socket

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

s.bind(('', 9999))
s.listen(1)
print('listening')
con, adr = s.accept()
print('connected')

with open('myfile.txt') as f:
    f.seek(0,2) # go to end of file
    filesize = f.tell()
    f.seek(0)
    sent = 0

    for line in f:
        con.sendall(line)
        sent += len(line)
        print('%s of %s' % (sent, filesize), end='\r')
        sys.stdout.flush()

con.close()
```

This code sends the file, and then closes.  If you want it to repeatedly send the file, or send it to mulitple clients, then you can extend it to do it, but it's a bit more complex.